# Comparing two strings together

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have array called `sev[w]` where w ranges from 1 to 21.
the array contains the following:

```
CRITICAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
CRITICAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
CRITICAL 
CRITICAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
CRITICAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
INFORMATIONAL 
INFORMATIONAL
```

I am to compare the string and print shte

```
if [ "${sev[0]}" == CRITICAL ]
 then 
    echo "shte"
fi
```

`sev[0]` has `CRITICAL` stored in it
However it doesn't work.
Thanks for your help!

EDIT
**The code [bashscript](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11729130/).

The [mibwithtraps](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11729141/).**

Comment: Does your script has a `#!/bin/bash` line at the start? What command are you using to run the script?

Comment: its bash. The code [bashscript](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11729130/).The [mibwithtraps](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11729141/)

Comment: Please post also `mibwithtraps`. The problem is likely there. Also to notify other users of a comment of yours use @username.

Comment: @Maythux @ kos I am adding this to the question itself

Comment: I tested your code and it works. I just copy-pasted `bashscript` and `mibwithtraps` into the same directory and ran the script, it outputted `21`, `CRITICAL` and `shte`. I suggest you to do the same and try again, you probably have some weird characters in it.

Comment: Damn it. I don't know whats going on, it just doesn't print `shte`.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested you? i.e. delete `mibwithtraps` and `bashscript` and recreate them copy-pasting them from pastebin. Then run the script using this command: `bash bashscript`. If you want to notify me use @kos, keep in mind that you can notify only one user per comment, so if you try to notify two the second one won't receive the notification.

Comment: @kos Okay. I copied it into a  new file and it works. Thanks! Any idea why this was happening with my old file?

Comment: Have a look at my answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your `mibwithtraps` file was created using Windows and therefore has `\r\n` line endings. That would break your script:

```
$ printf 'foo\r\n' | while read a; do 
    [[ "$a" == "foo" ]] && echo 'Matches!' || echo 'No match!'; 
done
No match!
```

As you can see above, the `\r` is included in the variable, so it doesn't actually match unless you include it in your test:

```
$ printf 'foo\r\n' | while read a; do 
    [[ "$a" == "foo"$'\r' ]] && echo 'Matches!' || echo 'No match!';
 done
Matches!
```

This is something you always need to take into account when dealing with files created on another OS. A simple way of checking is to pass the first line of your file through `od -c`. Doing that on the text from your pastebin (need to download the original, copy/paste won't work), I get:

```
$ head -1 dmvHuedP.asc | od -c
0000000       a   d   a   p   t   e   c   .   m   i   b   ,   s   C   S
0000020   I   S   m   a   r   t   1   ,   .   1   .   3   .   6   .   1
0000040   .   4   .   1   .   7   9   5   .   2   .   5   .   0   .   1
0000060   0   1   ,   C   R   I   T   I   C   A   L   ,  \r  \n
0000076
```

So, the `\r` was indeed the problem. Next time, you can use `dos2unix` to remove these:

```
$ head -1 dmvHuedP.asc | dos2unix | od -c
0000000       a   d   a   p   t   e   c   .   m   i   b   ,   s   C   S
0000020   I   S   m   a   r   t   1   ,   .   1   .   3   .   6   .   1
0000040   .   4   .   1   .   7   9   5   .   2   .   5   .   0   .   1
0000060   0   1   ,   C   R   I   T   I   C   A   L   ,  \n
0000075
```

Just run

```
dos2unix file > newfile
```

Alternatively, you can use standard UNIX tools:

```
tr -d  '\r' < file > newfile
sed -i 's/\r//g' file
```

Comment: Thank you, `mibwithtraps` was actually from windows. Very helpful!

Comment: @SamFlynn you're welcome, this is a classic issue and it's bitten all of us at least once. Note that the answer you have accepted is not really correct. It suggests that you need spaces around the variables but that would actually break. Consider `a=$(printf ' foo \n'); [[ "$a" == " foo " ]] && echo 'Matches!' || echo 'No match!';` and `a=$(printf ' foo \n'); [[ " $a " == " foo " ]] && echo 'Matches!' || echo 'No match!'; `. Whitespace is significant and is taken into account when matching.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```
if [[ "${sev[1]}" == "CRITICAL" ]]; then
   echo "shte"
fi
```

Take a look for [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide:Arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html#ARRAYSTROPS)

UPDATE:

I make a test. I think you miss with array numbers sev[1](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html#ARRAYSTROPS) is not critical it's INFORMATIONAL. sev[0] still have CRTITICAL and not empty

Here a simple test:

```
sev=( CRITICAL INFORMATIONAL )

if [[ "${sev[0]}" == "CRITICAL" ]]; then    echo "shte"; fi
```

output is:

```
 shte
```

Now:

```
if [[ "${sev[1]}" == "CRITICAL" ]]; then    echo "shte"; fi
```

output is Empty

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24907/discussion-on-answer-by-maythux-comparing-two-strings-together).

Answer (score 1):

As per [your comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637449/comparing-two-strings-together#comment910787_637449), you probably had some weird character somewhere in your script.

The most straightforward solution in this case, having the input file and the script have been posted to paste.ubuntu.com and having them been cleaned after the upload, [as I suggested you in the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637449/comparing-two-strings-together#comment910779_637449) and [as you did](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637449/comparing-two-strings-together#comment910787_637449) is to delete `mibwithtraps` and `bashscript` recreating them copy-pasting the version on paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Anyway, I can find the weird character? I am kind off pissed off and want to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Look at the hex of your critical/information file. You can bang one out in c in about 10 lines and that many minutes for a file of that complexity. Check your echo-ing and comparing the correct array index in your code, there maybe a bug in your debug code